# SQL help - count all serialNumbers except those with specific cases

Tags: sql, ssms

I need help with writing a case statement inside of a where clause.

Let's say we have a bunch of serial numbers stored in a database.
They are prefixed with some letters to denote their group.

Here is what I need to accomplish:

Exclude all serial numbers that begin with 'GIU' unless some conditions apply:

- If the serial number starts with GIU and is 15 chars long and the last 4 numbers are less than 5000, then exclude it, otherwise include it.
- If the serial number starts with GIU and is 16 chars long and the last 5 numbers are less than 10000, then exclude it, otherwise include it.

ex. GIU930798246071 should be included because: begins with GIU -> 15 chars long -> 6071 > 5000.

ex2. GIU9307982410621 should be included because it begins with GIU -> 16 chars long -> 10621 > 10000.

ex3. GIU930798243071 should be excluded because 15 chars long -> last 4 digits (3071) < 5000.

If I wanted to run a query to count these results, I tried:

```
select count(serialNum) 
FROM serialNumbers 
WHERE serialNum not like (
case when LEN(serialNum) = 15 and SUBSTRING(serialNum, 1, 3) = 'GIU' and RIGHT(serialNum, 4) < 5000 then 'GIU%' 
when LEN(serialNum) = 16 and SUBSTRING(serialNum, 1, 3) = 'GIU' and RIGHT(serialNum, 5) < 10000 then 'GIU%' end)
```

I'm trying to append the results of the case statement to the not like statement if those conditions apply.

Running the query returns null, so I know some part of the case is ruining the entire query.

Also, there are other serialNum who prefix start with other letters which it should also be counting.

I basically just need it to count all serialNums except the ones that start with GIU for these specific cases.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes things might be simpler than you think. I rearranged your WHERE-clause just to match the specs you provide in the description. I get something like this.

```sql
select count(serialNum) 
FROM serialNumbers 
WHERE
  serialNum not like 'GIU%' or
  (LEN(serialNum) = 15 and CAST(RIGHT(serialNum, 4) AS INT) >= 5000) or
  (LEN(serialNum) = 16 and CAST(RIGHT(serialNum, 5) AS INT) >= 10000)
```

Does this help?

Note that I explicitly casted the last 4 or 5 positions of the serial number to an integer. I assume the query will fail if those positions are not numeric. There are solutions for such cases as well, but for clarity I omitted them here.

**Edit:**

There is an alternative solution, assuming that the above query's logic is correct.

A 4-digit number larger than or equal to 5000 has the form `5nnn`, `6nnn`, `7nnn`, `8nnn`, or `9nnn`. A 5-digit number larger than or equal to 10000 does not start with a 0.

Using LIKE pattern matching for those cases, you could probably use the following query as well:

```sql
select count(serialNum) 
FROM serialNumbers 
WHERE
  serialNum not like 'GIU%' or
  (LEN(serialNum) = 15 and serialNum like '%[56789]___') or
  (LEN(serialNum) = 16 and serialNum like '%[^0]____')
```

Note that I used an underscore in the LIKE-patterns here to match any single character. I simply assume that they will actually be digits.

**Edit 2:**

Sorry. Re-reading your question, I probably got the last digits checking the wrong way around. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

So, what you could do is do a column to confirm what you are looking for (or not).  Once you get it confirmed, then do it.  By taking a slight shift from what Bart provided, you need to explicitly INCLUDE the "GIU" as part of the condition

what DONT you want...

```
       ( left( serialNum, 3 ) = 'GIU'
   AND LEN(serialNum) = 15
   AND CAST(RIGHT(serialNum, 4) AS INT) < 5000 )

     OR  

       ( left( serialNum, 3 ) = 'GIU'
   AND LEN(serialNum) = 16
   AND CAST(RIGHT(serialNum, 5) AS INT) < 10000 )
```

So if the where clause was the ABOVE, you would ONLY get those in the excluded realm.  So to invert this,

```
WHERE NOT ( above condition1 or condition2 )
```

thus

```
   WHERE 
      NOT (
              ( left( serialNum, 3 ) = 'GIU'
          AND LEN(serialNum) = 15
          AND CAST(RIGHT(serialNum, 4) AS INT) < 5000 )
    
         OR  
    
              ( left( serialNum, 3 ) = 'GIU'
          AND LEN(serialNum) = 16
          AND CAST(RIGHT(serialNum, 5) AS INT) < 10000 )
        )
```

Comment: At first glance, your logic seems to be right as well. As an exercise, I am trying to derive your logic to mine and vice versa using boolean algebra, but I am failing at some point. I will look at it later. ;) I do know that you might want to avoid an OR in a where clause to optimize index usage. That's difficult with my logic (so I would probably have to use ugly UNIONs), but in your case you could probably rewrite `NOT(condition1 OR condition2)` to `NOT(condition1) AND NOT(condition2)`, right?

Comment: @BartHofland, yes, the NOT and NOT would also work.